# How to recover Firefox 3.5 bookmarks after upgrade to Windows 7 from XP

Tags: windows-7, firefox, upgrade, bookmarks

I updated my computer from Windows XP to Windows 7.  It creates a folder called windows.old, but I am unable to locate the old Firefox bookmarks profile.  Where can I locate this or was it deleted in the upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the file bookmarks.html from

```
C:\Windows.old\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<old profile>\
```

to

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<new profile>\
```

Comment: Somewhere in these paths should be the user name, shouldn't it? I think it is where the double slashes are:

From 

\Windows.old\Documents and Settings\YourUserNameHere\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\

To

c:\Users\YourUserNameHere\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\\

Comment: The username was always there but I played a bit with the formatting and some markers removed the <username> part.

Comment: Okay, I already guessed that.

Comment: Right, I expected to find it there, but there is no 'Application Data' folder!  Where would the upgrade have moved that, or would it delete it?

Comment: You must enable the display of hidden and system directories

Answer (score 2):

I actually use a Firefox add-in called X-Marks (also works for IE) that stores your bookmarks to their server, allowing you to sync your bookmarks across machines (and also useful when upgrading a machine).  It won't help you if you didn't use it before you upgraded, but it could be useful for others who dont want to go through the same trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore everything by just copying your previous profile from

```
C:\Windows.old\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\
```

to

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\
```

. Then, edit the file `profiles.ini`

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/XXX.default
```

Replace `XXX.default` with the name of the profile folder.